# cloudant replication regex

Tags: couchdb, replication, cloudant

I am trying to replicate only the design documents via $regex between environment which unfortunately seems to replicate ALL documents. Any insight on how to limit my documents to _design/* easily via a regular expression. Is there something else that needs to be enabled for this to work? The following replication document is at the source database.

{
  "_id": "8615eee5c90e8fb333210f7dae6e52fc",
  "_rev": "15-1cffa4c19bc77878c0ce7206d03dd7e3",
  "source": "https://user:password@381d7eb2-96cf-4822-9e06-a9637895546e-bluemix.cloudant.com/forms",
  "target": "https://user:password@a8250b7c-d403-43a1-838a-a9d522b5aa42-bluemix.cloudant.com/forms",
  "selector": {
    "_id": {
      "$regex": "^_design/"
    }
  }
}

Comment: i am able to use the same $regex and replicate only design docs. can you delete the replication document and make a new POST request to the source db _replicate?
POST: https://user:password@381d7eb2-96cf-4822-9e06-a9637895546e-bluemix.cloudant.com/_replicate
BODY: { "source": "https://user:password@381d7eb2-96cf-4822-9e06-a9637895546e-bluemix.cloudant.com/forms", "target": "https://user:password@a8250b7c-d403-43a1-838a-a9d522b5aa42-bluemix.cloudant.com/forms-new", "create_target": true, "selector": { "_id": { "$regex": "^_design/" } } }